# What is a good practice to serialize a large index on a server?

Tags: java, serialization

I want to cache an index with well over a million documents returned from a MongoDB collection. I am building a Java class for each document and add specific attributes from the resulting classes to the index (currently implemented as HashMap). When reaching 100k documents I'm already getting trouble with my local memory, so I want to cache the whole index on the server for analysis.

What is a good practice to do so? I can hardly build the whole index and serialize it on the server since I'll run into memory pitfalls again. Sending each mapping to the server via HTTP seems like a lot of unnecessary requests (or doesn't it?). I could get access to a Tomcat server, however this seems unnecessarily complicated for the task.

Comment: I'm not sure you should. It will just get out of date. A simple and small index-based query to the server might well be sufficient. Every time I've introduced an application cache into a system I've regretted it. 20% performance improvement for several hundred percent increase in complexity and unreliability and specifically in unresolved cache coherence problems.

Comment: What option exactly are you referring to?